# the website created is for editing images with frames

Tags: django

The django website I created is not saving any of the images in my Profile model.

this is my views.py

```
def SaveProfile(request):
    saved = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get the posted form
        MyProfileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if MyProfileForm.is_valid():
            profile = Profile()
            profile.name = MyProfileForm.cleaned_data["name"]
            profile.picture = MyProfileForm.cleaned_data["picture"]
            profile.save()
            saved = True
    else:
        MyProfileForm = Profileform()class Profile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media')

   class Meta:
      db_table = "profile"


    return render(request, 'saved.html', locals())
```

this is models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media')

   class Meta:
      db_table = "profile"
```

this is forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
   picture = forms.ImageFields()
```

I cannot save, download or display the chosen image from the form.

Comment: You upload the images to media, have you set the url for the media folder in settings and urls.py?

Also you should use a modelForm here -> [Django modelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: yes i have set url in settings but not in urls,can you help how to set in urls.py

Comment: Can you post your urls.py file too, then I can help you

Comment: urls.py urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^about.html', about_page),
    url(r'^upload.html',upload_page),
    url(r'^frames.html',frames_page),
    url(r'^frame1.html',frame1_page),
    url(r'^frame2.html',frame2_page),
    url(r'^frame3.html',frame3_page),
    url(r'^frame4.html',frame4_page),
    url(r'^frame5.html',frame5_page),
    url(r'^frame6.html',frame6_page),
    url(r'^index.html',main),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @TM.96 Ive posted my urls.py